# How do i use JPA 2 to connect to multiple data sources?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, java-ee-6, jpa-2.0

I have two databases in MSSQL ,and i want to connect to them using JPA2 I have managed to get it working with one . Can some one help me how do i do that?

Thanks a Lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure two persistence units and use two `EntityManagerFactory` (one per persistence unit).

Comment: Thanks Pascal! I am new to JPA , and its good that good help is around :)